# Sum the values of a groupby from dataframe columns using a pattern in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Context: I'm trying to get the sum of the groups created using a groupby using a list of patterns that are present on the dataframe columns.

For example, let's say we have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'123_Pattern1_a':[0,1,2],'X_Y_Pattern2_X':[3,4,5],'Z_D_Pattern2_Y':[4,5,7],'312_Pattern1_Z':[8,2,4]})
```

I now would like to create a group by using the "Pattern" and get the sum of values for those columns for each row

If we have a list like this:

```
pattern = ['Pattern1','Pattern2']
```

With the dataframe above, the output should be another dataframe as such:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame({'Pattern1':[8,3,6],'Pattern2':[7,9,12]})
```

Basically, "concatenating" all the columns that have a specific pattern on the given column name and get the sum of these values by row

I was trying something like this:

```
pattern = ['Pattern1','Pattern2','Pattern3',...]

grouped = pd.DataFrame(data_media.groupby(data_media.columns.str.extract(pattern, expand=False), axis=1))
```

But it doesn't work since extract is a regex and I'm using a list with the patterns. How could I create a regex that would work for this problem? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: have you updated the input? I modified my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `melt` and `pivot_table`:

```
pattern = ['Pattern1','Pattern2']

df_final = (df
 .reset_index().melt('index')
 .assign(variable=lambda d: d['variable'].str.extract(fr'({"|".join(pattern)})'))
 .pivot_table(index='index', columns='variable', values='value', aggfunc='sum')
)
```

One option using `wide_to_long` and `groupby.sum` (works with previous example before OP update):

```
pattern = ['Pattern1','Pattern2']

df_final = (pd
    .wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=pattern, i='index', j='x',
                 sep='_', suffix='.+')
   .groupby(level=0).sum()
)
```

output:

```
       Pattern1  Pattern2
index                    
0           8.0       7.0
1           3.0       9.0
2           6.0      12.0
```

Comment: @ROO yes, I wrote the second one before you updated the question ;)